# how to access multidimensional array input in C++ mex file

Tags: c++

I have written my program in c++ and needed to write a c++mex function to pass input parameter and retrieve some output values in matlab. but i have been facing some issues accessing my multidimensional array. here follows a piece of what i have written and the error message.
w was declare as follows:

```
double **W;

W[i][j];

for  (int i=0;i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<6;j++)
    {
        //B[j + 6*i] = W[i][j];
        B[j + 6*i] = W[i + 6*j];     
    }
}
```

and when compiling i get the following error message:

```
cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double’ in assignment
```

Comment: So why didn't you use the commented-out code? Also, avoid using C arrays and pointers.

Comment: use B[j+6*i] = &W[i][j] in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2-D array represented as double** W needs to have space allocated. First you need to allocate each row. The code below illustrates this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int rows = 6, cols = 6;
double **W; 

W = new double* [rows];

// allocate each row
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    W[i] = new double [cols];
}

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<6; j++) { 
        // do work here
    }
}

// clean up in the end:
if (W != nullptr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        delete[] W[i];
    }
    delete[] W;
    W = nullptr;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: i have included the <cstddef> library but still get this error : RBM.cpp:587:10: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: You may be running a compiler that does not support C++11. Use NULL in the place of nullptr.

Comment: yes that works for me , you are genius :) thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The following code is wrong:

```
double **W;

W[i][j];
```

Either declare `W` as:

```
double W[i][j];
```

Or read: [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new).

Your 2D array accessing syntax

```
B[j + 6*i] = W[i + 6*j];
```

is wrong too.

Are you trying to do this?

```
B[j][6*i] = W[i][6*j];// if B is 2D array
```

Or

```
B[j + 6*i] = W[i][6*j];// if B is 1D array
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he isn't trying to do either.

Comment: Also *please* don't recommend using  `malloc`.

Comment: the value of W is computed somewhere else and is a pointer to another pointer containing the values i need to retrieve in matlab (i mean stored into a variable). so i guess am trying to get a 2D array. Also am a bit new in C++

Comment: @JNW, then after line `double **W;` what does `W[i][j];` statements means?

Comment: i just tried : > B[j][6*i] = W[i + 6*j] // got this error: RBM.cpp: In function ‘void mexFunction(int, mxArray**, int, const mxArray**)’:
RBM.cpp:574:17: error: invalid types ‘double[int]’ for array subscript

Comment: sorry i forgot to mentioned : > B[j + 6*i] = W[i][6*j]; // the following compile but I am having a run time Error this time.

Comment: @JNW, its very hard to guess why you get run time error because you didn't post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have been trying to send the full function here but the site settings are a bit complex and keeps refusing to post it. something about post containing codes and need to be on a kind of format.

Comment: yes i get something with following as well... <B[j + 6*i] = W[i][6*j];>